# Chapter insists on beginning on the left side

Tags: koma-script, chapters, classicthesis, scrbook

I am typesetting a book using the Classic Thesis package and Scrbook.  I've added the usual copyright page behind the title page and a blank page behind the dedication page.  Since the contents page is only one page, I also need to add a blank page after it so that Chapter 1 doesn't begin of the left side.
Here's the problem: when I try to add a blank page after the contents, so that Chapter 1 begins on a new page (on the right side), *two* new pages are added so that, yet again, Chapter 1 begins on the left side.  Why is latex insisting that the chapter being on the left side and how can I get it to simply add 1 blank page and allow Chapter 1 to begin where is should?  I believe this is happening with every chapter.

I've tried several different methods of placing a blank page all with the same result. Here's my MWE where the commands to add a blank page are blocked off with %:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  % Font encoding
\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers, linedheaders=true]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{moredefs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{papersize={5in, 8in}, top=0.75in, bottom=0.75in, headsep=0pt, outer=0.6875in, inner=0.815in}
\title{~~~~~\\
{\Huge \textsc{Book Title}\\}}
\author{Author Name\\
\\ {\large ~~~~}}
\date{}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead*{\pagemark}
\chead{\headmark}
\renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{\chaptername\ \thechapter:\enskip}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\maketitle
\newpage
\null
\vfill
\begingroup
\parindent 0pt
Copyright \textcopyright{} 2022 \par
All rights reserved. 

\vspace{0.2in}
\hspace*{2cm} ISBN:  \par
\newpage
\begin{center}
    \emph{Dedication.}
\end{center}
\newpage
~
\newpage 
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setlength{\parindent}{16pt}
    \tableofcontents 
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{page}{0}

    \pagestyle{scrheadings}
%\newpage
%~
%\newpage 
\chapter{Chapter 1}\thispagestyle{empty}
\lipsum[1-11]
    
\chapter{Chapter 2}
\lipsum[12-15]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is due to the `twoside` class option. When you load the class with `\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{scrbook}` only one empty page is added (which does have the 'Contents' header though).

Comment: Thank for your feedback. Page numbers added !

Comment: Off topic: The redefinition of `\chaptermarkformat` is useless because `classicthesis` redefines `\chaptermark` to not use `\chaptermarkformat`. Note, that `classicthesis` loads `titlesec` and the usage of `titlesec` is not recommended with a KOMA-Script class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With some simplifications of your code.

[image: d]

[image: e]

```
% !TeX TS-program =  lualatex

\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{scrbook}
%\usepackage{titlesec} % to be loaded by classicthesis
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  % Font encoding
\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers, linedheaders=true]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{moredefs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{papersize={5in, 8in}, top=0.75in, bottom=0.75in, headsep=0pt, outer=0.6875in, inner=0.815in,includefoot}
\title{~~~~~\\
    {\Huge \textsc{Book Title}\\}}
\author{Author Name\\
    \\ {\large ~~~~}}
\date{}
%\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% loaded by classicthesis

\clearpairofpagestyles
\chead{\headmark}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}% changed <<<<<

\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
    \maketitle
    \newpage
    \null\vfill
    \parindent 0pt
    Copyright \textcopyright{} 2022 \par
    All rights reserved.    
    \vspace{0.2in}
    \hspace*{2cm} ISBN:  \par
    \newpage
    \begin{center}
        \emph{Dedication.}
    \end{center}
    
    \tableofcontents \pagenumbering{arabic}     
    
    \pagestyle{scrheadings} 

    \chapter{Chapter 1}
    \lipsum[1-11]
    
    \chapter{Chapter 2}
    \lipsum[12-15]
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Now the table of contents is missing I think?

Comment: That works!  Just needed to add the page numbers back in.

Comment: I do not understand which page should get the arabic number 1. With your suggestion the last page of the ToC  gets page number 1, ie. if the ToC has two pages the second page gets page number 1.  Either use `\cleardoublepage\pagenumbering{arabic}\tableofcontents` (page 1 is the first page of the ToC) or `\tableofcontents\cleardoublepage\pagenumbering{arabic}` (page 1 is the first page of chapter 1)

Comment: `\pagestyle{scrheadings}` can be/should be removed.  Loading  package `scrlayer-scrpage` activates the pair of page styles `scrheadings` (i.e. `scrheadings` and `plain.scrheadings`) automatically. So `plain.scrheadings` is used on chapter pages including the first page of ToC and `scrheadings` is used on the other pages including the second etc. page of ToC.